# How to add an onclick event to a element that already has a hover animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation that runs when hovered over, but since mobile devices cant really hover over buttons I am trying to add a click function.  I am having difficulties trying to add a click event to my already existing code.

So currently, the animation works by hovering over the Menu and buttons transition from behind it.  I am trying to have the same transitions animate when the Menu is clicked.  I have tried .getElementByID() but dont know which id's to put where to get it to work, or if I need to add a class in HTML or not.

```
<div class="btn">
      <button id="menu" type="button"><h5>Menu</h5></button>
      <div id="box"><a href="info.html"><button id="button-1" type="button"><h4>Info</h4></button></a></div>
      <div id="box-2"><a href="about.html"><button id="button-2" type="button"><h4>About Us</h4></button></a></div>
      <div id="box-3"><a href="contact.html"><button id="button-3" type="button"><h4>Contact</h4></button></a></div>
    </div>
```

```
#menu:hover ~ #box{
  animation-name: myanimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Any help that would improve my understanding of Javascript would be greatly appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: Actually hover in Desktop is kind of a Click on mobile (at least in Android ones)

Comment: Add a new selector to your rule, ` #menu.active ~ #boxactive, #menu:hover ~ #boxactive` . You can set a handler on #menu that adds a class active to itself

Answer (score 0):

What you need to add a class to the button on a click event. This class will contain the CSS animation which will invoke the animation when you click the button. But because you have multiple buttons you will need to pass the event to get the element you want to add the class too. Look at the example below for reference.

```js
function animateBtn(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var element = e.target || element.srcElement; 
  element.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
#menu.active ~ #box{
  animation-name: myanimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
      <button onclick="animateBtn(event);"" id="menu" type="button">Menu</button>
</div>
```